# Xcode 4.4 keeps crashing

Tags: xcode

Every time I open my app in Xcode 4.4 it crashes.  It never used to do this in Lion and being very close to submission after about 6 months of work, I'm pretty annoyed to say the least!
This is part of the crash report if it helps; I can't make head nor tail of it.  If anybody can help me, I'd be forever in your debt.

> UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSBadBitmapParametersException): Overflow allocating bitmap backing store.  Cannot back bitmap with 1152921504606846976 bytes per row, -9223372036854775808 height, and 1 planes.

Comment: Is it *just* your project, or any project?

Comment: Do you get the alert that clang has crashed? This is very common in 4.4 and 4.4.1 - a known problem. The official response is to use 4.5 pd4 until fixed.

Comment: Unable to open my project here as well, was doing well in Xcode 4 in Lion.
Once i've upgraded to Mountain Lion and had to reinstall Xcode 4.4. Unable to launch the project (Xcode just hangs). Updated to Xcode 4.4.1 and still the same. Are we missing something here? Should i reinstall my entire Mountain Lion and Xcode 4.4.1 from fresh?
Anyone having the same issue?

Comment: It was in 4.4.  I have today upgraded to 4.4.1 and it is doing the same thing.  I have now tested other apps and it seems it's just this app for now.  I deleted all of the pictures because I saw the word bitmap, but probably overkill as they're all .pngs!  Haha however, I don't know if it is best to start again from scratch?  I have a git repo, but even going back a few steps doesn't fix it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to Apple as a bug report I'm afraid; they said from the crash report that it looks like a bug.  Thanks to everyone for their help.

Answer (score 1):

Um, have had that issue what I did Is delated xcode and redownloaded it.
Hope that works!

Comment: Already tried that, but unfortunately it didn't work for me.  Many thanks for replying though friend.

Comment: Did you try restarting your project?

Comment: Yes many times, I've done a clean on the odd occasions it has booted up.  Still no joy...

Comment: What I have done in the past is started a new project and then just copy the code over from the project thats not working. To the new project.

Comment: I'm contemplating it, it's just I think the problem may be in the mainstoryboard.storyboard.  My app has about 100 viewcontrollers in there and redoing all of them will take me some considerable time.  Does anybody know of quick ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Experiencing such kind of problems, I got the following conclusion: 3 files can be corrupted

1. Your project file, in that case try using time machine to get the
   one which will work
2. The XCode prefs: /Users/xample/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
3. Your project's Derived data ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

If one of those is corrupted, it will corrupt the 2 other one. To recover a project, start trashing the pref and derived data, then try to open your project. Reinstalling XCode did not solved my problem, using the DP4.5 neither in my case.

HOWEVER: Installing the [latest "Command Line Tools for Xcode](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/command_line_tools_os_x_mountain_lion_for_xcode__august_2012/command_line_tools_for_xcode_os_x_mountain_lion_aug_2012.dmg) solved it (and this is probably the first thing to try)

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, I've tried all of the above and it hasn't worked.  I've also spoken to Apple and they've asked me to file a bug report judging from the crash report.  I hope they'll be able to provide me with some help, particularly with my app but I'm not holding out much hope!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds weird but Xcode 4.4 has problem with printing out logs of big strings. 
I had the same problem, and I deleted an NSLog which printed a big amount of text, and the crash stopped...

Answer (score 1):

For me, I'm getting this crash when trying to open a particular .storyboard file from the project view. If I open the file directly through finder, it doesn't immediately crash so long as the window is small. If I try to resize it or scroll one of the views into view, it will crash again.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue with XCode 4.5.1. It keep crashing whenever i open storyboard and it throws following error:

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4G1004
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSBadBitmapParametersException): Overflow allocating bitmap backing store.  Cannot back bitmap with 1152921504606846976 bytes per row, -9223372036854775808 height, and 1 planes.

Apple released new developer preview version of XCode 4.5.2 last week, which has fix for all intermediate crashes that we saw in previous versions. This build is available in https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

You can try this.